# Is there a way to concatenate parent's value in array of deep nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have an array of nested objects. I need to update the id property of each node by concatenating all its parent names.

id should be value of the **name** property of current node joined with **name** property
od it's parents separated by '/'

```js
treeData = [{
    name: 'Infiniti',
    id: '',
    children: [{
        name: 'G50',
        id: '',
        children: [{
            name: 'Pure AWD',
            id: ''
          },
          {
            name: 'Luxe',
            id: ''
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: 'QX50',
        id: '',
        children: [{
            name: 'Pure AWD',
            id: ''
          },
          {
            name: 'Luxe',
            id: ''
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'BMW',
    id: '',
    children: [{
        name: '2 Series',
        id: '',
        children: [{
            name: 'Coupé',
            id: ''
          },
          {
            name: 'Gran Coupé',
            id: ''
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: '3 Series',
        id: '',
        children: [{
            name: 'Sedan',
            id: ''
          },
          {
            name: 'PHEV',
            id: ''
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Expected Outcome

```js
[{
    name: 'Infiniti',
    id: 'Infiniti',
    children: [{
        name: 'G50',
        id: 'Infiniti/G50',
        children: [{
            name: 'Pure AWD',
            id: 'Infiniti/G50/Pure AWD'
          },
          {
            name: 'Luxe',
            id: 'Infiniti/G50/Luxe'
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: 'QX50',
        id: 'Infiniti/QX50',
        children: [{
            name: 'Pure AWD',
            id: 'Infiniti/QX50/Pure AWD'
          },
          {
            name: 'Luxe',
            id: 'Infiniti/QX50/Luxe'
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'BMW',
    id: 'BMW',
    children: [{
        name: '2 Series',
        id: 'BMW/2 Series',
        children: [{
            name: 'Coupé',
            id: 'BMW/2 Series/Coupé'
          },
          {
            name: 'Gran Coupé',
            id: 'BMW/2 Series/Gran Coupé'
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: '3 Series',
        id: 'BMW/3 Series',
        children: [{
            name: 'Sedan',
            id: 'BMW/3 Series/Sedan'
          },
          {
            name: 'PHEV',
            id: 'BMW/3 Series/PHEV'
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I tried to use Array.prototype.reduce(), but I am unable to get the previous value to concatinate.

```js
    function updateTreeData(array) {
      return array.reduce((returnValue, currentValue) => {
        if (currentValue.children != null) {
          returnValue.push(Object.assign({}, currentValue, {
            children: this.updateTreeData(currentValue.children)
          }))
        }
        return returnValue
      }, []);
    }

    console.log(updateTreeData(treeData))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the recursion approach

```js
const treeData=[{name:"Infiniti",id:"",children:[{name:"G50",id:"",children:[{name:"Pure AWD",id:""},{name:"Luxe",id:""}]},{name:"QX50",id:"",children:[{name:"Pure AWD",id:""},{name:"Luxe",id:""}]}]},{name:"BMW",id:"",children:[{name:"2 Series",id:"",children:[{name:"Coupé",id:""},{name:"Gran Coupé",id:""}]},{name:"3 Series",id:"",children:[{name:"Sedan",id:""},{name:"PHEV",id:""}]}]}];

const populateId = (list, currentId) => {
    for(const item of list) {
     if(!currentId) {
           item.id = item.name
     } else {
        item.id = currentId + '/' + item.name
     }
     if(item.children) {
        populateId(item.children, item.id)
     }
  }
}


populateId(treeData)

console.log(treeData)
```